# Can I Access The Objects Of The Previous Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I've used [PreviousPage Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) to access the controls of the previous page but how can I access objects and instances of classes I initiated in the previous page!

Thanks For Your Time =)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast the PreviousPage object to the type of the previous page if it exposes public properties and methods that are going to be of use to you.  However this isn't the same instance of the page that you created during the previous request.  Any properties of then page that you set during the previous request will no longer be set.

One of the downsides to the webforms model is it encourages you to think that web programming preserves state from one request to the next, when in fact it doesn't.

Comment: I created an object (Obj1) in the previous page and added some values to the object properties from the textboxes in the previous page and called a Page.Response.Redirect(NextPage);

now, there is no possible way to know the values of the properties of Obj1 ?

Comment: You can't store them in this object. The object is lost at the end of the request.  There are lots of places you can store the values, in a database, in session state, in the query string, in view state (tricky for cross-page posting). Which to use depends on many factors, security, how long you want the persistence to last, how large the data is, whether it needs to be accessed across servers (e.g. in a web farm).  Check this out : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx

Comment: Well James, Thanks a lot for the clear explanation...but if I don't want to store them in the db right now, I mean I need to let the user know what information did he enter in the first page so he could confirm the change or the insertion of the item, it will include nothing high profile but still a queryString would be too much I need something hidden, what do you suggest would be my best choice ? Marked as answer btw!

Comment: In this case I would recommend using session state.  So in the event handler of previous page you store the information in session state,  and then in the page load of the next page you retrieve it from session state and put it into the next page.  If instead of using Response.Redirect you used Server.Transfer then the next page is served from the same request - so then you could use the state in the request object.  This would be cleaner but some people don't like the fact that the URL doesn't change.

Comment: well in most cases It's not the best way, as you want your pages accessible, BUT and this is a big but :D in my case I want to confirm the information which is technically I don't want any one or the search engines to find it!

+2 THANKS A LOT..I couldn't even come up with such a thing =)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you persisted the state of the objects, etc. from the previous page then they are gone.